# Apple UUID while updating whole project with same bundle ID

Tags: ios, xcode, uuid

I have an application written in mixed Obj-C/Swift, it uses UUID for identification of a device. I am rewriting whole application in Swift, using another project with same bundle ID. However when I try to update old project build with Xcode using new one build with Xcode too, new application UUID is different. What I am missing? Shouldn't it be the same because I am using same bundle ID?

Comment: Depends of development or production. I think. How  did you generate it?

Comment: please add your code

Comment: @user3344236 @a.masri what code should I provide? `UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString` returns different values

Comment: save your unique id to keychain

Comment: @canister_exister actually helped me to fix the problem, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, it indeed stays the same, old application was saving one in keychain and using it even after reinstall.

Answer (score 2):

Does UUID mean `UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString` ?

If so, it changes in some situations documented in Apple developer page.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor

> The value in this property remains the same while the app (or another app from the same vendor) is installed on the iOS device. The value changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them. The value can also change when installing test builds using Xcode or when installing an app on a device using ad-hoc distribution. Therefore, if your app stores the value of this property anywhere, you should gracefully handle situations where the identifier changes.

Comment: I am installing same bundle apps using same Xcode. I am not really sure, that `The value can also change when installing test builds using Xcode or when installing an app on a device using ad-hoc distribution.` means it should change

Comment: Yes, it depends on dev or production. Mean release for store, or just deployed for testing.They differ.